# vim puppet lint suppress warnings from syntatic

Tags: vim, puppet, lint, suppress-warnings, syntastic

Does anybody knows how to suppress warnings like:

```
[80chars] line has more than 80 characters
```

Syntastic has function to suppress certain warnings via a regex. Does anybody know how the regex for that warning would look like?

Syntastic example:

```
let g:syntastic_quiet_messages = {
    \ "!level":  "errors",
    \ "type":    "style",
    \ "regex":   '\m\[C03\d\d\]',
    \ "file:p":  ['\m^/usr/include/', '\m\c\.h$'] }
```

Comment: So, what did you try?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
let g:syntastic_quiet_messages = {
       \"!level":  "errors",
       \ "type":    "style",
       \ "regex":   '[80chars] line has more than 80 characters',
       \ "file:p":  ['\m\c\.p$'] }
```